# Count files in Home and send mail - Powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-4.0

I'm not Powershell guru but do anyone of you have some script which counting files in an folder and automaticlly send mail to user? Our users have an roaming profile

> (\\profile-srv\%username%)

Folder name is the same as username. Is it possible to have an script which will count files in every home folder and send email to user?

> domain is: FirmaBis.org  total users: 150

So count in ex. aaba and send mail to aaba@firmabis.org 
Count next aaca and send mail to aaca@firmabis.org

So script will count files and send mail to user based on folder name and + firmabis.org.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide a code example of your own work? SO is not a script writing service. Own effort is required. None of us are here to do the (paid) job of someone else.

Comment: I don't push anybody to send me anything. It's just an simple question if anybody have something.

Answer (score 2):

```
# Get just the directories in the user directory share, ignore any files, loop over them
Get-ChildItem -Path '\\server\share' -Directory | ForEach-Object {

    # List all the files in the current folder (loop variable $_ is the folder)
    $FilesInFolder = @($_ | Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Force -File)

    # Count the files
    $NumFiles = $FilesInFolder.Count

    # Calculate how many MB they take up, and show it to 2 decimal places
    $FileSize = $FilesInFolder.Length | Measure-Object -Sum | Select-ExpandProperty Sum
    $FileSize = "{0:.0}MB" -f ($FileSize/1MB)

    # Build the email message
    $Message = @"
    Hi,
    The folder for account ($($_.Name)) has $($FilesInFolder.Count) files in it.
    They add up to $FileSize
    "@

    # Send the message through an SMTP server which is configured to allow
    # unauthenticated relay emails from the computer running the script.
    Send-MailMessage -SmtpServer yourmailserver -To "$($_.Name)@FirmaBis.org" -From 'script@FirmaBis.org' -Body $Message
}
```

Untested, but ...

Answer (score 1):

I have not seen anything that you have tried so far. Just to give you a set off:

You can get the list of Files count using the combination of *Get-childitem* and *.Count* method.

```
 ( Get-ChildItem D:\FolderName | measure-object).Count
```

You can store the output in the variable.

Then, You can pass the variable as a *BODY* in *Send-MailMessage* with which you can send emails.

Comment: I didn't do anything beacase I wasnt sure where to start. Thanks:)

Comment: @DavidJackowiak: Acceptance of the answer will be appreciable. You try first, then we are there to guide you. :)

Comment: `Measure-Object` is redundant for counting. `(Get-ChildItem).Count`

Comment: @FrodeF.: If you have 1 or 0 item(s), then count() method won't be accurate. Thats why measure-object

Comment: In PS3+ it will for 1+. For older versions and 0, make it an array `@(Get-ChildItem).Count`

Comment: Yes then it will work. Just to avoid that directly measure-object is good